# 200s being sent instead of 304s for images in Android / IOS?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, safari, webkit

In a web-app I am making, I load in pages by appending their HTML to the DOM (via appendChild -- note that I append CLONED nodes), after a user clicks "next" or "previous" in the interface.

I check if a node's image has already been loaded by checking its .complete value. (or height, or naturalHeight, etc., etc..) If it has not been loaded, I add a temporary loading background until it is loaded, checking with a setTimeout.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0; public"
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "modification"
```

In my Samsung Note 2 default "Internet" browser*, it seems that images are cached, and 304 "not modified" requests ("unchanged") are always sent when the image doesn't change -- .complete is true if the image was not changed.

There's no problem on PCs, either. I get 304s, as expected.

In (other) Webkit browsers (IOS 7 AND at least Android 4.1.2!), .complete (and all the other values) is false for a split second (possibly a 304, but looks like a 200.. it is very difficult/currently impossible for me to test with the Note 2 using the Google debugger)

My question is (after searching for 3 hours I still can't find an answer) -- is Webkit on mobile phones sending 200s when it should be sending 304s? Is this a bug? Is there some other bug? Is there ANY way to fix this?

Note that the solution would not involve caching stale images!

*: The default Samsung Internet browser is an older Webkit browser, I believe... not 100% sure.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of the problem. You can see clearly that "complete" is "false" in Chrome on android.. (and also on the PC, although in my actual web app this wasn't a problem on the PC..) http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7ar/1/ ... Compare this with http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7ar/2/, which doesn't clone the node.